# Implementar websocket que requiere headers en java

Tags: java, websocket

Estoy realizando una aplicación para recopilar una serie de datos de varias webs.
En una de ellas para hacerlo debo comunicarme con el servidor mediante un WebSocket.
Este WebSocket tiene una serie de parámetros en el Header:

```
        Connection: Upgrade 
        Pragma: no-cache
        Cache-Control: no-cache
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
        Upgrade: websocket
        Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
        Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7 
        Sec-WebSocket-Key: k+ghkoMFCs/FZ3DkJtNKyg==
        Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
        Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: zap-protocol-v1
```

Estuve buscando la forma de implementar el WebSocket en java SE y di con Jetty, tras revisar varios ejemplos en ninguno de ellos he visto que sea posible definir variables del Header. Existe alguna forma de implementar esta tarea con Jetty o debo buscar alguna otra alternativa

Mi código es el siguiente, intenté seguir algunos ejemplos que encontré pero la verdad que es la primera vez que toco este tema y estoy algo perdido.

```
   public class Bet365ServerRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dest = "wss://premws-pt3.365lpodds.com/zap/?uid=5072739771513135";//
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();


        try {

            Bet365ClientSocket socket = new Bet365ClientSocket();
            client.start();
            URI bet365Uri = new URI(dest);
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            client.connect(socket, bet365Uri, request);
            socket.getLatch().await();
            socket.sendMessage("#?P?__time,S_280C2F9D9EF86C59847B787B7312C1FC000003");
            Thread.sleep(10000l);



        }catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                client.stop();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}



@WebSocket
public class Bet365ClientSocket{

private Session session;

    CountDownLatch latch= new CountDownLatch(1);

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onText(Session session, String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Message received from server:" + message);
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {


         UpgradeRequest request = session.getUpgradeRequest();
         //request.setH
            Map<String, List<String>> params = request.getParameterMap();

            List<String> language = params.get("lang");
            if (language != null && language.size() > 0) {
                String lang = language.get(0);

        System.out.println("Connected to server");
        this.session=session;
        latch.countDown();
    }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String str) {
        try {
            session.getRemote().sendString(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }


}
```

El único mensaje que me aparece en la consola tras ejecutar el código es el siguiente:

```
2018-11-20 19:09:55.419:INFO::main: Logging initialized @761ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código, para ver qué has intentado hacer? Será más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Podrías mostrar el error que te arroja el navegador.

Comment: He dejado el mensaje de la consola, porque parece que no avanza más que de ese punto